# Turn a number into a byte string literal, similar to stringify!()

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a macro that would turn a number into a byte string literal, similar to how the `stringify!` macro can turn its argument into a `&str`.

More concretely, how would I write this:

`byte_stringify!(10) -> b"10"`

I will be using this to create a large number of `const` structs, so I can't really rely on calling a method on `str`.

More ambitiously, I'm actually trying to prepend and append some text before turning the argument into a byte string:

`make_arg!(10) -> b"x10y"`

**Update:**

Where did the old `bytes!` macro go? I think I want:
`bytes!(stringify!(10))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't; at least, not without writing a compiler plugin, which is far beyond the scope of a simple Stack Overflow response.

There's some basic documentation on the subject in the [Compiler Plugins](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/compiler-plugins.html) chapter of the Rust Book, though do keep in mind that compiler plugins *only* work on nightly Rust; they do not work in any stable or beta release, thus also locking any crate that uses them to nightly Rust.

Sorry about that.

Comment: What happened to bytes! macro? That seems to be what i want.

Comment: @JasonN It got removed, and at least [two](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/566) [proposals](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/18702) to bring it back were knocked back.

Comment: That's strange. It is the same as stringify!() but for bytes. Why not remove stringify too? Same arguments apply. I'm going to start another proposal but with my use case (differenr from the other two). There seems to be quite a few use cases that the devs didn't think of.